# jquery finding innertext of anchor tag

Tags: jquery

my anchor tags

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
```

  Armed Combat
    Armed Combat 1-2
      Dance -1
      Dance - 2
      Armed Combat 1-5
    Armed Combat 1-3
      Death -1
      Death - 1
    Armed Combat 1-4
    Armed Combat 1-6
  Dance

how to assign hter to selected menu item (label) when it matches reqid 
 var reqid = "<%=Request["id"]%>";
here am getting all inner texts

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            if (reqid.length != null) {

                $('#cssmenu').filter(function () {

                    var hter = $(this).text();

                    $('#selectedmenuitem').html(hter);

                });
            }
        })
```

please tell me ...

Answer (score 0):

you can check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/EMrWR/1/)

In that you can assign your value to `testVar`

Below is the code

```
$("#cssmenu").children("a").each(function(){

if(this.text==testVar)
{

  $("#"+this.id).text("Matching anchor tag");

}
else
{

}

});
```

A small update,
If you need to change the href or any other value of that matching anchor tag you can use [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/EMrWR/2/)